# How to combine these 2 queries into 1 and avoid extra code

Tags: php, mysql

I have 2 tables in database, table **users** lists all users and their inviters (referrers) , table **donations** lists all the donations

The only connection between 2 tables is the **user_id** in table **donations** which is the **id** (Primary AI) in table **users**

What i want to do is get count of all users in table **users** which have ref='$referrer' and then see how many of them have donated and they are in **donations** table (each user can donate multiple times so it shouldn't count 2 donations as 2 users)

What i have tried:

first i get each ref of that inviter

```
SELECT id FROM users WHERE ref='$referrer'
```

then i put it in a while() loop and for each one of them i check if they have a donation

```
SELECT * FROM donations WHERE user_id='$id'
```

if they are found that counts as 1++

### Issue

issue is if a user invited +500 people, then i send 500 queries in a loop with PHP, which takes time and resource

### What is needed

I need a single Query with sub-Query to take only referrer id (ref='$referer') and give me count of all user X's referrals (every user with ref='55' in table users for example) which also have at least one donation in donations table

something like:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM donations WHERE user_id = (SELECT id as user_id FROM users WHERE ref='$referer')
```

Can any one please help me with that

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM donations d INNER JOIN users u ON d.user_id=u.id WHERE u.ref='$referrer' GROUP BY d.user_id
```

Comment: Thanks, so the final count of $referrer's active referrals is getting mysqli_num_rows($result); of the result of query in PHP?

Comment: no matter what i put in $referrer this query always return same result, which is count of all donations for each user (not related to $referrer)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
SELECT users.id, COUNT(*) `donations_count`
FROM users
INNER JOIN donations ON user.id = donations.user_id
WHERE users.ref='$referrer'
GROUP BY users.user_id
```

Comment: Thanks, i tried it but got error: Column 'id' in field list is ambiguous

Comment: Change "SELECT id" to "SELECT users.id" and that should take care of it